# JBPM Business central - Data set not working with aggregate function

Tags: postgresql, jbpm

I have an issue with the Data set - Execution server. I am using PostgreSQL as DB. I want to calculate the difference between the two dates column for my report. The query I have used in DB is:

Query 1:

```
SELECT end_date as end,
               start_date as start,
               processid as pidd,
              AGE(end_date, start_date) as duration
  from processinstancelog
```

Query 2:

```
select end_date,start_date,processid, end_date - start_date as
duration from processinstancelog
```

Both queries reflecting the correct expected result in Postgres DB. But when I am using the same queries in the Data set>Execution server it's not showing the "duration" column.

**Question**

Can anyone please advise what is issue why the data set is not showing the duration column?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer, I deleted the old setup and installed the new setup for JBPM and data set start appearing

Answer (score 0):

Both queries reflecting the correct expected result in Postgres DB. But when I am using the same queries in the Data set>Execution server it's not showing the "duration" column.

> > How do you use in the query in the execution server? Are you implementing advance query functionality? If yes can you please share the exact steps you are following and your advance query definition to review.

Comment: No, I am not using the advance query functionality?- I am using a query in the execution server to create new Data set.

**Business central Setting > data set > New data set> Execution server (here i am using query to create data set)**

Comment: Hi @ChavanAbhijeet - Can you please have a look on it, i will be very grateful to you for this.

Comment: Hi @ChavanAbhijeet or anyone can please have a look at it, I will be very thankful

Comment: Hi, you are implementing advance query only. Can yo try below SQL and share your result with us : SELECT end_date as end, start_date as start, processId as pidd, AGE(end_date, start_date) as duration from ProcessInstanceLog.   You were using incorrect coulmn and table name. Names are case sensetive.

Comment: Hi this query is working in DB but not in business center advance query tool,getting error
java.lang.RuntimeException:org.kie.server.api.exception.KieServicesHttpException:Unexpected HTTP response code when requesting URI 'http://localhost:8080/kie-server/services/rest/server/queries/definitions/cab8c9d9-5ae7-4794-9b3f-604392352e2b/filtered-data?mapper=RawList&page=0&pageSize=10'! Error code: 400, message: "The request could not be understood by the server due to malformed syntax

Comment: Also when I am changing the query like

'SELECT end_date as endT, start_date as startT, processId as pidd, AGE(end_date, start_date) as duration'
from ProcessInstanceLog

 it’s working in business center but not getting the duration column there.